# Replace str value in pd df by sampling from a pandas array

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a pandas df

`df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 'X'], 'B': [0.1, 0.1, 'X', 0.1, 0.1], 'C': [0.1, 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X']})`

```
 A    B    C
 0.1  0.1  0.1
 0.1  0.1   X
 0.1   X    X
 0.1  0.1   X
  X   0.1   X
```

and an array

`<PandasArray> [0.9999999999999304, 0.9999973764241584, 0.9999997377248664, 0.9615117313882438,  0.871479832883895, 0.9999999999998652, 0.9999999999999994, 0.9999029359407972,  0.999999984174712, 0.9944689702907784] Length: 10, dtype: float64`

I would like to replace the values X by sampling from the array such that the distribution of the values in the array is represented in the df in the locations with the value X

I have tried

`df[df == 'X'] = np.random.choice(arr, replace=True)`

which gives this output

```
 A    B    C
 0.1  0.1  0.1
 0.1  0.1  1.0
 0.1  1.0  1.0
 0.1  0.1  1.0
 1.0  0.1  1.0
```

Does this randomly sample from the array and why are the values rounded? I would like to replace with the exact values from the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does this randomly sample from the array?

Yes, you are right.

> Why are the values rounded?

It is display problem, if convert to list get real data:

```
df[df == 'X'] = np.random.choice(arr, replace=True)
print (df.to_dict('list'))

{'A': [0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.9999997377248664],
 'B': [0.1, 0.1, 0.9999997377248664, 0.1, 0.1], 
 'C': [0.1, 0.9999997377248664, 0.9999997377248664, 0.9999997377248664, 0.9999997377248664]}
```

Comment: Interesting! Although, it has replaced all X with the same value in the array = 0.9999997377248664. How can I sample from the array such that the distribution of the values in the array is represented in the df in the locations with the value X?

Comment: @peter_parker - Unfortunately not understand - `the distribution of the values in the array is represented in the df in the locations with the value X`.

Comment: You are only sampling once and replacing every occurence of 'X' with that value. In order to get different samples for each 'X', you need to give the "size" parameter to the choice-function: ```df[df == 'X'] = np.random.choice(arr, size=df.shape, replace=True)```